# React native router flux : how to overrride burger button style?

Tags: react-native-router-flux

Is there way to customize padding / position... of the burger button.
In the [doc](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/API_CONFIGURATION.md), i just can find the drawerImage parameter to override the burger image...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there's a parameter for it : leftButtonStyle

Answer (score 1):

Saddly no option without forking. You can check the code here:
https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/src/NavBar.js. Padding and position is fixed.

Comment: do you know how to override the whole NavBar.js file? I mean inside src folder so it wont be reset on each npm i

Comment: You need to fork the repo, make your changes and let npm install the version from your fork. You can pass a github url in the package.json instead of a version

Answer (score 0):

in my case I use react-native-vector-icons getImageSource for the burger icon

```
componentWillMount() {
  Promise.all([Icon.getImageSource('bars', 16, 'black')])
  .then((values) => {
    this.setState({
       menuIcon: values[0],
     });
  });
}
```

then you do something like this:

```
const menuIcon = {
  uri: this.state.menuIcon.uri,
  height: 20,
  width: 20,
  resizeMode: 'stretch',
  color: 'white',
};
```

then in your tabs scene

```
<Scene
    key="main"
    type="replace"
    initial
    drawerImage={menuIcon}
    tabs
    style={{ backgroundColor: theme.navColor, justifyContent: 'center' }}
>
```